# android memory issue - app uses a lot of ram

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, ram

I have some problems with the memory usage of my android app and don't know what causes the high memory usage. When I start my app, it uses up to 40 mb ram (says DDMS) and when I open another app, my app gets immediately killed.

I read a lot about memory leaks and I'm unbinding drawables, running the GC and so on but my app still needs a lot of memory.

I have about 3mb resources in my app, but afaik they are loaded into ram on demand. Am I wrong? May this cause the 40mb of ram usage?

EDIT: I think I'm not having memory leaks because I can switch the orientation on each activity as often as I want and the app does not crash because of low memory. So it can't be a memoryleak, can it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do memory management into your android application, please free the resources which is no longer used, try to override onStop(), onDestroy(), onPause() methods of Activity which will keep track of activity stack.

in OnDestroy() method free your whole availed resources, so that another app can use the same resources again.

Comment: I already overrided onDestroy (I think its enough because I finish an activity after starting a new one) an unbind drawables (background images of linearlayouts) and call GC

Answer (score 0):

What data structures are you using? Very large data structures (long Lists, big graphs, big maps, etc) can quickly use up RAM.

It could also be that you're leaking the Context on orientation change in your app.

It could also be that your layouts are really badly designed along with some heavy data structures.

It's difficult to tell unless you describe a bit more about what your app tries to do.

Comment: I'm not using large data structures. i've got a lot of layout files and drawables, but each of them is small (and the layouts are not very complex). i've got a splash screen and then a small loginActivity which connects to a webservice. after successfully loged in there is an other not complex activity. the high number of drawables is just for choosing an image and get not loaded until you push a button. but before this, the app already uses 40 mb of RAM.

Comment: That's very strange. Sorry, I'm out of ideas at the moment